# extracting data from Index Exchange's headertag

Tags: javascript, header-bidding

I'm looking for a way to get data from Index Exchange's headertag in the browser for real-time analysis.
The headertag object supplies some function like 'apiready', but I'm looking for extended data on the bidding process.

Example of data is who won the bidding and for how much.

Comment: Can you give more context?

Comment: Need more info to clearly understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of points:

1. Please contact your IX account manager for more details.
2. The Index Wrapper does not mediate so it doesn't pick a winner, just passes all the bids returned by the timeout (or on all bidders responded) to DFP as key values.
3. There is not an object available in the standard wrapper that contains the bid responses you are looking for. We are working on adding such an object into the wrapper in a future release.
4. If the publisher is using the "Universal" wrapper then all bids are returned to the page via a publisher defined callback method. This would allow the publisher's javascript to see all the values you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There are definitely events you can subscribe to in Prebid and other wrappers. The event volume can be fairly large so keep that in mind.

For full disclosure, I'm the founder of http://PubWise.io. we created PubWise to track all of this data and a growing set of additional publisher focused data as well. All in an easy to setup package. We have a free tier for 1m pageviews that you can use to try it out.